# Ray library for parallel IO operation in Python

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, ray

I try to use the ray library, since it seems to offer a ton of speed and multiple processing.

I try to read and write multiple files from and to disc. This is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import time
import ray

ray.init()

allfiles = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(
    os.path.abspath("C:/Users/User/Desktop/FileIO/Inputfiles")
):
    for file in files:
        allfiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))

@ray.remote
def read_to_new_csv(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df.transpose()
    df.to_csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/FileIO/Output/" + os.path.basename(file))


start_time = time.time()
[read_to_new_csv.remote(x) for x in allfiles]
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

The code executes. However the csv file does not get saved on the output path. Without `ray` the code works fine. Does `ray` not work with IO operations?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you replace `[read_to_new_csv.remote(x) for x in allfiles]` with `ray.get([read_to_new_csv.remote(x) for x in allfiles])` does that change it? It's possible that the script is exiting before the tasks have finished executing, and so the tasks are getting canceled. The call to `ray.get` will block until the tasks have finished.

Comment: thank you very much, that works. I just saw your youtube video of 2019 meetup, awesome presentation :-). One further question if it does not take too much effort: I get a `Dashboard build directory not found` error now. Is there a way to ignore that. I need no dashboard :-/